# Symbol not found when using -ObjC/-all_load linker flags

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

after update to Xcode6, I got this code crash on IOS 7 with "`Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings`", can any one help with it

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    int notifyType = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)notifyType];
}
```

EDIT : 
hi all,
it's a runtime crash, not a compile time link error,

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings

and I was on Xcode 6.0 (6A313), So I should not use any #if to indicator iOS versions. And this code works fine on IOS 8 simulator, but crashes on IOS 7 devices

EDIT 2 :

Finally, this issue was fixed by these codes, I have mark the right answers below, thanks trojanfoe.

```
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    Class userNotifyClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings");
    if(userNotifyClass != nil)
    {
        id notifyInstance = [userNotifyClass settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notifyInstance];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}
else
{
    int notifyType = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)notifyType];
}
```

Comment: By "code crash" you mean "link error"?

Comment: @Daij-Djan Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you test on ARM64?

Comment: Provide screenshot, hardware you test on, etc..

Comment: hi Andy, I use iTouch 5 with 7.1.1, valid architectures armv7, base sdk IOS 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You must be compiling with an iOS SDK version less than 8 in order to get that link error.</strike>

To fix the issue use the iOS 8 SDK (i.e. Xcode 6) and check that the class exists at runtime using:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings")) {
    // do thing
}
```

**EDIT** After further information from the OP:

- He is using Xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK.
- He is using the `-ObjC` and `-all_load` *Other Linker Flag*.

It's the `-ObjC`/`-all_load` flags that stops the usual techniques of testing for a class to exist at runtime and using it selectively.

In order for the app to support iOS 7 and iOS 8 with `-ObjC` semantics, I can think of two solutions:

- Remove the use of `-ObjC`/`-all_load` linker flags in favour of `-force_load`, as that targets a specific library for "all load" (see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889914/can-the-objc-flag-be-applied-selectively-to-static-libraries)).
- Use a more dynamic (and error prone) approach of:

  1. Creating an instance of `UIUserNotificationSettings` using `NSClassFromString()`.
  2. Calling methods with `performSelector`.

I would favour the first approach.

Comment: hi, it's a runtime crash, something "weak link", not a compile time error

Comment: @wangsihao Are you using the `-ObjC` *Other Linker Flag*?

Comment: hi trojanfoe, I finally solve this problem by the second approach you motioned "Use a more dynamic (and error prone) approach of". I will put my code in the question's edit section. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are building your project with 'base SDK' 7.x
So you could change it to **8.0** or check current version during compilation:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_7_1       

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
#else
    int notifyType = (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)notifyType];
#endif
```

Comment: I use "latest iOS(iOS8.0)" as the base sdk.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying

Comment: thanks, I am trying with this solution, feedback later

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on XCode 6.1 @ iOS 8 SDK / iOS 7 deployment target. My app uses -ObjC linker flag as well.

Just ran app on iPhone with iOS 7.1.2 / ARMV7. I use the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Update: additionally tested on iPad 4 / iOS 8, iPhone 5s / iOS 8. All work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[image: change UIKit.framework to optional works to me]

change UIKit.framework to optional works to me

Answer (score 0):

UIUserNotificationSettings is available only on iOS8

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings") != nil) 
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: true, but he checks the selector already. this is a linker error

Comment: it's true, but I already has a selector check here, and I also tried the "NSClassFromString", still a crash with same error.

Comment: dyld: Symbol not found, runtime link error, I have Xcode Version 6.0 (6A313), should I update to 6.0.1 and have a try?