# -Objc Other linker flags gives duplicate symbol error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using `Unrar4iOS.Framework`. It works fine but when I add -Objc other linker flags. it gives me duplicate error.

```
    duplicate symbol __Z12CallbackProcjlll in:
    Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
    /My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.header in:
    Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
    My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.flags in:
    Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
    My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
```

I had require to add use Objc flag to use other library.

Comment: Check the code where you are importing the framework using #import. Check whether you are importing .h or .m file

Comment: If that doesn't work try removing and adding the framework again

Comment: I have checked its working fine if I remove linker flags

Comment: Have you tried removing the framework and adding it again?

Comment: yes number of times

Comment: How about using `-force_load`.

Comment: Can I look into your code. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: @Arun https://github.com/saru2020/SARUnArchiveANY..  ADD -ObjC in other linker flag

Comment: @Droppy its not working

Comment: @Mahavir OK, so update your question with the argument you are passing to `-force_load`.  It has to include the full path to the library you want to load all the symbols from.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25890484/3588973).

Answer (score 5):

If you are specifying the -all_load or -Objc flag and the static libraries has the same symbol name of classes in your project,
you’ll see these “duplicate symbol” errors in linking time.

reason why?

> **This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category.** While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.
>   
> from Apple official document.

In your project, Now, 3 symbol in Unrar4iOS.o has been crashed.

For example on your first duplicate symbol error log, 
__Z12CallbackProcjlll symbol crashed **in** 
(1) Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o

(2) /My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)

and the same pattern will go for the second and third duplicate symbol.

```
duplicate symbol __Z12CallbackProcjlll in:
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
/My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.header in:
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Unrar4iOS.flags in:
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SARUnArchiveANY-fgljekydpkmvrlgapbahtfvvhsdl/Build/Intermediates/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SARUnArchiveANY.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Unrar4iOS.o
My Project/SARUnArchiveANY-master/SARUnArchiveANY/vendor/Frameworks/Unrar4iOS.framework/Unrar4iOS(Unrar4iOS.o)
```

So, To summary your project symptom, Now, in your project,
**Unrar4iOS.framework and SARUnArchiveANY library crashes each-other with three duplicated symbol in : Unrar4iOS object file.**

Plus, below is the SARUnArchiveANY git repository introduction.
it already specified SARUnArchiveANY library contains Unrar4iOS.

> SARUnArchiveANY
>
> A very useful library for Unarchiving the .zip, .rar, .7z files for iOS.
>   Simply An Integration of the following libraries :
>
> **Unrar4iOS**
>   SSZipArchive
>  
>   LZMA SDK (7z)
>   
>  from https://github.com/saru2020/SARUnArchiveANY

To solve the problem, I recommend this link.
http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries

you could solve the problem because I did it before already.

Comment: The link http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries is no longer available :(